# How IBoutlet hold initial value being weak? Means some other strong object is pointing?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have created a button on storyboard and IBOutlet in source code for same.

When I try to re-initialize same outlet, its giving warning **"Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'button' is 'weak'"**.

I understand this point, because no strong pointer is pointing,so it will deallocate.
But initially button has value, if it weak then there must be other object pointing it strongly?

Similar case for Layout constraints IBOutlet.

In the case of button , I think it must view(But not sure).

But what will it be in case of layout contraint.

What if I want to achieve same thing by creating UI programmatically.

I mean a weak variable can keep same values as holding in case of UI creation by IB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you declare the IBOutlet? and how do you re-initialize same outlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the scene is loaded from the storyboard the button is added to the view hierarchy before the reference is assigned to the `@IBOutlet` property. Since the button is in the view hierarchy there is a strong reference to it.

When you say something like

```
self.buttonOutlet = UIButton()
```

The only reference to the new button is a weak property and the compiler warns you that the object will be immediately released.

You can use a local variable to hold a strong reference until the button is added to the view hierarchy.

```
let newButton = UIButton()
self.view.addSubview(newButton)
self.buttonOutlet = newButton
```

Comment: let newButton = UIButton(); 
self.buttonOutlet = newButton;

Why still no warning ? even view is not holding any reference.

Comment: Because `newButton` is holding a strong reference. If `newButton` goes out of scope (e.g. the function returned) before you add it as a subview the object will be released (but you won't get a warning)

Comment: #Paulw11 One more doubt,

Suppose I have created a button in some inner view with constant constraints (say leading 10, top 10, width 50, height 20) and created outlets for constraint(let assume for width only).

This will also be weak then how it's(width constraint) alive what is other strong pointer pointing to the same constraint ? because this constraint has nothing to do with view or any component other than button.

Comment: The button has a strong reference to the constraint. The button's superview has a strong reference to the button